# Dialogflow regex entity does not capture message phrase

Tags: regex, entity, dialogflow-es, message, detect

I have a message send to DialogFlow, look like: `I wanna go to <@U12A0GF233T>` and I want DialogFlow can detect `U12A0GF233T` as an entity.
So I created an entity `@place` with value `^\<@([A-Z])\w+\>`.
But when the message was recived, dialogFlow can not detect `@place`.
I tested my regex on https://regexr.com/, it's work, but it doesn't work on DialogFlow.
Did I make some mistake here?

Comment: Try using more words to describe what you need.

Comment: The pattern `^\<@([A-Z])\w+\>` by itself does not match `U12A0GF233T` in `I wanna go to <@U12A0GF233T>` Try it like this `^[^<>]*<@([A-Z]\w+)>` https://regex101.com/r/ps3V7J/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I made a mistake when I use regex pattern of Javascript for Python (^_^"). But with your pattern, when I test with `I want to move my home office to <@U12A0GF233T>` (for example). The result was returned is `office to <@U12A0GF233T>`. I change pattern to `^*<@([A-Z]\w+)>` and it's working. I dont know Python so I'm not sure this partern is true. But you saved me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe you just want `<@([A-Z]\w*)>`?

Comment: @DuyHưngAndrogyneTenor In that case, I think it should be `^<@([A-Z]\w+)>` instead of `^*<@([A-Z]\w+)>`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and Thefourthbird: I try to change to them but did not work in my cases.

Comment: @DuyHưngAndrogyneTenor Maybe you meant a dot before the asterix `^.*<@([A-Z]\w+)>` https://regex101.com/r/M2008Q/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird No, when I add `^.*<@([A-Z]\w+)>` to DialogFlow Entity value, it did not correctly detect the phrase `<@U12A0GF233T>`. When I use `^*<@([A-Z]\w+)>` and it detect correctly (at least for now in the cases that I have tried). Haha. I do not know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Google Dialogflow leverages [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2) C++ library for the regular expressions associated with the [entity](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/entities-overview), that might change slightly the general regexp dialect, just follow this RE2 [Syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) page.

In the explained use case, I've finished up regexp pattern adjusting either with:

`^*<@([A-Z]\w+)>`

Or

`\<@([A-Z]\w+)>`